# PrimeFlex not working on Angular Version 12.1.4

Tags: angular, primeng, primeflex

I have installed primeFlex(Version 3.0.1) on my angular application(Version 12.1.4). I followed the instructions on their webpage primeflex.com however, was unable to fix the error. I glanced over the network Tab and found that the CSS file was retrieved however it is not being applied to my application. I am not sure how to fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess how your using the library? Show your code!

Comment: Never Mind, I fixed it, it was the version issue. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @SulavDahal, can you elaborate what version issue, because I am facing same issue

Comment: @SandipGhadge so, when I installed Prime Flex it installed the latest version which was 3.0.1 however while I was following the Prime NG documentation I followed the documentation of Prime Flex V 2.0.0.   Prime flex version 3 and version 2 have different CSS classes to style the elements and apply those flex and grids, so that is why it's not working.

Answer (score 19):

In primeflex version greater than 3.0.0, **the tag "p-" was removed**, for example: `class="p-grid"` became `class="grid"`.

You can notice this by opening the file in **your_project/node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css**, you will see that there is no longer the "p-" tag in the classes.

If you want to continue using the tag, I recommend you install primeflex **version 2.0.0**, changing:

```
...
"primeflex": "2.0.0",
...
```

[See](https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/migration)

Comment: if i could give you 2 upvotes i would have done it, thank you very much that answer helped me

Answer (score 1):

in primeng doc for angular 12 and above  for this date (january 2022) the primeflex versin doc is 2.0  - but it install new version 3+
the docs for primeflex 3+ is https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/

Answer (score 0):

Angular 12 is not compatible with latest Primeflex version.

Install v2.0 with this command

```
npm i primeflex@2.0.0 --save
```

It should fix the issue.